# Change class of TabBar in xCode4

Tags: uitableview, xcode4, uitabbar

I'm following the following tutorial that was made in xCode3

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBnPfAtswgw

As I'm using xCode4, I followed everything until the part where she changed the class of the first tab to UINavigationController as I didn't got that option! Please help.

Regards,
Ali

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without having to delete and drag new controllers in:

To change the type of an object:

- From within Xcode 4, open your .xib file.  If the interface builder object viewer isn't expanded, make it so by dragging it's right boarder out, or clicking that little 'play' button at the bottom.
  [image]
- Expand the Tab Bar Controller object to see it's children, and select the object you wish to change
  [image]
- Then choose it's Class type from the right panel, Identity Inspector.  (To display the Identity Inspector, go menu: View > Utilities > Identity Inspector).

  [image]
- You can open and close that right panel using the buttons on the top right of Xcode.  You can get to the various utilities by clicking the utility buttons, or through View > Utilities.
  [image]

To rearrange tabs in the Tab Bar Controller, drag and drop them in the interface builder object viewer (this will change their position in the actual tab bar too).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found alternative solution by deleting the default created tabs and drag new controllers which have the classes I need in my app.